# Paginate generate number

Tags: asp.net

I want to add page number in my application, like `1 2 3 4`. My paginated class code is:

```
public bool HasPreviousPage
{
    get
    {
        return (PageIndex > 0);
    }
}
public bool HasNextPage
{
    get
    {
        return (PageIndex+1<TotalPages);
    }
}
```

This code generates link and goto next page, but can't display page number.

Comment: I don't think there's nearly enough code here to see what's going on.  Assuming there are integer properties/members called `PageIndex` and `TotalPages` then these properties will successfully return booleans, but beyond that there isn't much here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Pages
{
    get
    {
        for(var page=1; page <= TotalPages; pages++)
            yield return page;
    }
}
```

You could use it for rendering the pages in your page (i.e. using a repeater).

Hope it helps.